# Getting undefined setting object's property value using this in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to set `fullname` property of the object `person` using `this`, but got undefined when logging out the full name.

```
var person = {
  name:'yask',
  fullname: this.name + ' Srivastava'
}

console.log(person.fullname);
```

This is strange, as using `this` while using inside the function refers to the object. Here it looks like it's being referred to global object.(Window maybe..?)

Comment: You can't reference an object inside itself with `this`. `this` is function scoped.

Comment: Note that you haven't constructed the object yet, so `this` refers to the function scope you're currently creating the object in.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ,while using this inside the function.. then also we haven't constructed the object yet but it still works ?

Comment: The really simple solution is to just add that property later, as in `person.fullname = person.name   + ' Srivastava';` after the object is created.

Comment: @adeneo Solution sounds good, but I still can't understand why `this` doesn't point to the current object `person`?

Comment: @adeneo why is `this`  function scoped? Can you link me some more material to understand this? I tried googling, couldn't find relevant things.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the use of [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get),

```
var person = {
  name:'yask',
  get fullname(){ return this.name + ' Srivastava' }
}

console.log(person.fullname);
```

Basically the `this` in your case will point the context of <strike>lexical scope</strike> the function of the object, not the object itself.

Comment: note, in ES6 only, and if you're going down this road, you might as well structure your code a little better by using a real object definition or class and creating an instance of that

Comment: I am having trouble understanding `Basically the this in your case will point the context of lexical scope the function of the object, not the object itself.` Can you please explain this?

Comment: @yask The `this` that you are using will equals to the `this` belongs to the scope where the object is present. `function test(){ var self = this; var obj ={ a :this }; console.log(self == obj.a); //true }`